# Set a minimum price for ERC20 Token

Tags: tokens

Is it possible to set a minimum price that a token can trade at? If as an example the floor was set at $1USD / and someone tries to sell the token at a lower price $0.75USD, the order will be rejected.

Thanks very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major problems here:

1. The transfer functionalities have no idea whether the token is transferred because of a trade or due to some other reasons.
2. Even if you could figure out when the token is being traded, you would need some way to figure out what is the trading price. The contract has no idea about any dollar values. You would probably need to do some complicated functionality to compare some trade values to some stablecoin (DAI?) values, or something similar.

So, in essence, that's not possible. Mostly because the contract isn't aware of any trading patterns or prices - it simply transfers tokens when asked to.